# Installed turtle package not recognized by vscode

Tags: python, anaconda

I have an issue with working with the turtle package in python. I have Anaconda installed on my computer. Within Anaconda I have installed the turtle package with pip command (there is no conda install option for turtle as to my knowledge).

When I start a jupyter notebook and import turtle everything works just fine.

When I start vscode from conda and use the same python environment, I get an import error from vscode saying: importerror: cannot import name Turtle.

Why is this happening and how could I start turtle in vscode?

Thank you!

Comment: did you set the name of your `.py` file `turtle.py`? or is there any `turtle.py` in the directory which you're coding in?

Comment: oooh my goooood...that was the problem! how could I bee such a stupid one! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install PythonTurtle` in the vs code terminal

Comment: tried that, unfortuntally does not work (requirement already satisfied):
PS C:\Lori\PROJECTS\Project_INDEED> pip install PythonTurtle
Requirement already satisfied: PythonTurtle in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Shayan solved the problem in the comments... I was so stupid to name my file turtle.py... no comment
I renamed the file and works really great!
Thank you Shayan!